# I need to loop through an arrayList in Java and multiply the returned results together. I am struggling with the multiplying of the returned results

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I am new to Java and I am struggling with my Loops.I want to create a basic program that will analyse betting results.My Fixtures Class Constructor:

```
public Fixtures(String homeTeamName,double homeTeamOdds,String 
     awayTeamName, double awayTeamOdds,double drawOdds,String result) {
  this.homeTeamName=(homeTeamName);
  this.homeTeamOdds=(homeTeamOdds);
  this.awayTeamName=(awayTeamName);
  this.awayTeamOdds=(awayTeamOdds);
  this.drawOdds=(drawOdds);
  this.result=(result);
}
```

I have created an ArrayList of Fixture objects:

```
Fixtures fixture2= new Fixtures("ManchesterUnited",1.6,"Spurs",3.1,2.8,"home");
Fixtures fixture3= new Fixtures("Manchester Citeh",1.3,"Burnley",4.1,3.8,"home");
Fixtures fixture4= new Fixtures("Newcastle",2.1,"Bomouth",4.1,2.6,"away");
Fixtures fixture5= new Fixtures("Everton",2.1,"Watford",4.6,2.3,"away");
Fixtures fixture6= new Fixtures("Chelsea",2.1,"Brighton",4.1,3.8,"draw");

ArrayList<Fixtures> games = new ArrayList<Fixtures>();

games.add(fixture2);
games.add(fixture3);
games.add(fixture4);
games.add(fixture5);
games.add(fixture6);
```

Now I want to loop through the ArrayList and find the fixture where the result was a "home" win and multiply the home win odds together.What I have below prints out the 2 homeTeamOdds. I want to then multiply them together. I'm stuck.Any help on finishing this Loop would be greatly appreciated

```
double x=0;
for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++){
    if (games.get(i).getResult().equals("home")){
        x=(games.get(i).getHomeTeamOdds());

        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your variable to `1`, because multiplication by 0 doesn't make sense. Your check for "home" is fine, just multiply the result of `getHomeTeamOdds()` with `x`:

```
double x = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++) {
    if (games.get(i).getResult().equals("home")) {
        x *= games.get(i).getHomeTeamOdds();
    }
}
```

Instead of using the ol' skool method, you can also use the Java Streams API:

```
double d = games.stream()
    .filter(t -> Objects.equals(t.getResult(), "home"))
    .mapToDouble(t -> t.getHomeTeamOdds())
    .reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
```

In my opinion, the intent of your operation is more clear.

- `.filter(t -> Objects.equals(t.getResult(), "home"))` filters all elements where the result is "home", discarding all others;
- `.mapToDouble(t -> t.getHomeTeamOdds())` selects all `homeTeamOdds` values;
- `.reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b)` applies a mathematical reduction to the collected values, having 1 as initial value, and the reduction operation as a lambda expression: multiply each element with the previous result.

Comment: Thank you. I must look at Java Streams API. I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want

```
    Fixtures fixture2 = new Fixtures("ManchesterUnited", 1.6, "Spurs", 3.1, 2.8, "home");
    Fixtures fixture3 = new Fixtures("Manchester Citeh", 1.3, "Burnley", 4.1, 3.8, "home");
    Fixtures fixture4 = new Fixtures("Newcastle", 2.1, "Bomouth", 4.1, 2.6, "away");
    Fixtures fixture5 = new Fixtures("Everton", 2.1, "Watford", 4.6, 2.3, "away");
    Fixtures fixture6 = new Fixtures("Chelsea", 2.1, "Brighton", 4.1, 3.8, "draw");

    ArrayList<Fixtures> games = new ArrayList<Fixtures>();

    games.add(fixture2);
    games.add(fixture3);
    games.add(fixture4);
    games.add(fixture5);
    games.add(fixture6);

    double x = 1;
    for (Fixtures game : games)
        if (game.getResult().equals("home")) {
            x *= game.getHomeTeamOdds();
        }

    System.out.print(x);
```